# Where does centos linux store tar file errors

Tags: linux, logging, error-handling, centos, tar

I was making the tar of `whole system` as `root` and in the last i get this

`tar: Exiting with failure status due to previous errors`

Now i have closed the screen i am not able to find what were the errors that caused tar to exit.

In which log file i can find those errors

Comment: Not a programming question....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Non-services generally do not store log files on Linux. Unless `tar` was called by a service the logs are not stored anywhere.

Run it again and don't close the screen.